# how to pass variable from controller to directive using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am writing click event in controller i.e in controller getting variables but i want to pass these variables into directive i am writing following sample code.
sample.html:

```
<div ng-controller="myController"
      data-angular-treeview="true"
      data-tree-model="roleList"
      data-node-id="roleId"
      data-tree-id="mytree"
      data-node-label="roleName"
      data-node-children="children" 
      data-ng-click="selectNode(currentNode)"

      >
    </div>
```

samplecontroller.js:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
     $scope.selectNode=function(val)
        {
            $scope.nodeval=val.roleName;
            $scope.nodeid=val.roleId;
            $scope.treedata={roleName:val.roleName,roleId:val.roleName};
            $scope.nodedata=JSON.stringify($scope.treedata);

        };
     });
```

Sampledirective.js:

```
app.directive('tree1', function($rootScope) {
    function compile(scope, element, attributes) {
        return {
             pre:function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

                },
                post:function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

             scope.data=scope.nodedata;
                   alert(scope.data);

                    });
                }

        };
    }

    return {
        compile: compile,
        scope: {
            nodedata:'=',
         },
           restrict: 'AE', 
           templateUrl: '/sample.html'
    };
});
```

in samplecontroller.js the nodedata getting roleName and roleId but i want pass this nodedata from samplecontroller.js to Sampledirective.js.inside compile function of 'post' method in alert palce i want get this 'nodedata' so please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why just don't use `link` instead of `compile`? [Docs Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

the definition of `link` is the follwing:

> function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }

where `scope` will controller's scope.